# Find example of analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm looking for example of function $f(z)$ holomorphic in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ and such that the following hold:

1. Outside the unit ball $|z|<1$ function $f(z)$ doesn't have zeros, it has at least one zero inside the unit ball $|z|<1$.
2. $f(z)$ has the finit limit $\lim\limits_{z \to \infty} f(z) \neq 0$.
3. $f(z)$ has a sufficient singularity at $z=0$ with, if it is possible, given Laurent expansion.

Is there some analogue of the Mittag-Leffler theorem that can be applied here?

Comment: $f(z) = \sin{(\pi/(2 z))}$ wouldn't do the trick?

Comment: @RonGordon yes, I think it does, but it is also interesting what we can say about given Laurent expansion

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that; $f(z)$ would not have such a Laurent expansion about $z=0$ I think, no?

Comment: @RonGordon I mean the generalisation of Mittag-Leffler theorem in this case. It allows us to construct a function with pole at given point and with given Laurent expansion in this pole. But it works only for meromorphic functions (all singularities must be poles).

Comment: $f = \frac p q, p,q$ polynomials of same order, zeros and poles where you want them, and that's all, because if it's well behaved at $\infty$ the ratio of any two such objects is entire and bounded.

Comment: @mike I don't want poles, I want essential singularity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{a_n\in\mathbb{C}\}_{n\ge 1}$ be any sequence which satisfies that: $(1)$ it has infinitely many nonzero terms, and $(2)$ $\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1/n}=0$. Then $$f_0(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{z^n}$$ is convergent and holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. Moreover, $0$ is an essential singularity of $f_0$, so by [Little Picard Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem#The_theorems), $\mathbb{C}\setminus f_0(\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\})$ contains at most one point. Let $a_0$ be any complex number which satisfies that $(1)$ $-a_0\in f_0(\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\})$ and $(2)$ $|a_0|>\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|$. Then $$f=a_0+f_0$$ satisfies all your requirements.